# issues to save and retrieve the image in android?

Tags: android, image, canvas, save

I have an application that uses a canvas function, I want to save and retrieve all images (whatever I saved).?

**issues**

I can save and retrieve the single image only

Dynamically I save the image,(image001,image002......)

**update**

```
   try {
                toDisk.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File("/mnt/sdcard/image00"+saveimageid+".jpg")));
                saveimageid++;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I retrieve the image from image001.

```
File imgFile = new  File("/mnt/sdcard/image001.jpg");
if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to load all the files that match imageXYZ.jpg.

I have no idea why you save the files like "00"+saveimageid+".jpg.
If you want to make sure the filename is equally long (or at least three positions) do something like

```
new File(String.format("/mnt/sdcard/image%03d.jpg", saveimageId))
```

To retrieve the files you might

```
File dir = new File("/mnt/sdcard/");
File[] images = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
     @Override
     public boolean accept(final File dir, final String filename) {
         return filename.matches("image[0-9]+\\.jpg");
     }
});
```

Then you can use the `images` array however you please.

As a sidenote: If this is Android you should not assume that external storage is placed in /mnt/sdcard. Use [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())

Comment: i have updated my code ,by using this code my image is not saved and i cannot retrieve

Comment: Why did you update your code? This is not how SO works. This makes my answer irrelevant to the question. If you update you should also keep the original code.
What is your problem? Your comment doesn't describe the problem. You should have an array containing > 0 Files that you can use.

Comment: actually my problem is i want to save the image randomly and i want to retrieve the image.By using this code i cannot retrieve the image and save the image properly.kindly help me.i will updatemy original code

Comment: You are giving to little information. What do you mean by "i cannot retrieve the image and save the image properly"? How far do you get? What does your debugging tell you?

Comment: am try to save the image dynamically,(image001,image002,image003,image004....and so on))like this format i want to save the image.Then i want to retrieve all saved images.How to save like this

Comment: I gave you examples on how to generate the filename and how to list files matching those names. I'm afraid I do not have time to give you a full solution, nor is it the purpose of stack overflow. I can answer specific questions, but not give you full applications.